# Value 24 for hourOfDay must be in the range [0,23]

Tags: java, android, time, java-time, localtime

I've got a REST service that I use in my Android app that gives me a time, time only, but it returns also something like

`"24:38:00"` or `"25:15:00"`

so, what I need is to parse this time and put a real result out in 24h format. It should be

`"00:38:00"` and `"01:15:00"`

I tried use this way

`LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime(timeModel.getTimeString());`

but i have this error now `Cannot parse "24:38:00": Value 24 for hourOfDay must be in the range [0,23]`

How can I solve? I need only the time not date

Comment: How about.. if the hour is >= 24, subtract 24 from it?

Comment: @ShioT do you think can be the best way? Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: `hourOfDay % 24`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could assume that these time Strings are not following any rules, because if `24` and `25` exist as values for the "hour" part, why wouldn't they reply with `37`?

You can use this to clean this up:

```
private static String modifyTimeString(String s) {
  //the hour might only be 1 digit, so "the first 2 chars" is not a safe approach
  int colonIndex = s.indexOf(':');
  String hoursString = s.substring(0, colonIndex);
  Integer hours = Integer.valueOf(hoursString);
  if(hours < 24) {
    return s;
  }
  /*while(hours >= 24) {
    hours -= 24;
  }*/
  //smarter, see ronos answer:
  hours = hours % 24;
  //put a leading 0 in there for single-digit-hours
  hoursString = hours.toString();
  if(hours<10) {
    hoursString = "0" + hoursString;
  }
  return hoursString + s.substring(colonIndex);
}
```

Calling `modifyTimeString("25:15:00")` returns `"01:15:00"`

Comment: I tried this one and it's working pretty well. Of course, the server has a problem. But I can't fix it. This method it's a good workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can split time string and get hour, minute, second and then use `LocalTime.of`

```
String timeData = "25:15:00";
String[] timeParts = timeData.split(":");
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of(Integer.parseInt(timeParts[0]) % 24,
                                   Integer.parseInt(timeParts[1]), 
                                   Integer.parseInt(timeParts[2]));
```

Comment: I wouldn't really trust the input values to always give you 2 digits for the "hour" part...

Comment: when they misuse the hour, why wouldn't the abuse the minutes and seconds as well? This would probably be the most robust when you use `% 60` for both minute and second

Answer (score 1):

You should really fix this server. If this is impossible though, you'll have to work around this bug with something like

```java
String fixServerTime(String time) {
  if (time.startsWith("24")) {
    return "00" + time.substring(2)
  } else {
    return time
  }
)

// elsewhere
LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime(fixServerTime(timeModel.getTimeString()));
```

Comment: Sometimes there is a reason for times to look like that. In my knowledge, Japanese latenight television schedules count past 24, so instead of "3 am of Wednesday" they say "27 o'clock of Tuesday".

Comment: This answer does not cater for hour numbers that are 25+, but OP can probably take the idea and tweak it a little.

Comment: Well, the ISO standard permits only 0-23, java.time APIs are based on that standard, so to use them successfully in such "custom" environments one would have to "hack around" :)

Answer (score 1):

### Use a lenient parser

What you need is a leneient formatter for parsing — or more precisely, a formatter with lenient resolver style (a formatter also has a parse style, it doesn’t need to be lenient in your case).

```
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);
    String timeString = "25:15:00";
    
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeString, timeFormatter);
    System.out.println(time);
```

Output:

> 01:15

You don’t need any hand parsing, nor any `if` statement, nor any modulo operation. You don’t need to handle any special cases. You can leave it all to the standard library. Which is good both for readability and for trust in the code.

Comment: Wow! This is the best of all the answers on this page!